# how to limit number of curls per second php

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot

I want to run a telegram bot on a server. I created it with php and it sends requests to telegram servers with curl. bot telegram server prevents more than 30 requests per second, this means that I should send 30 requests per second with curl, at maximum. how can I limit number of curl per second to 30 ?

Comment: bot question is obvious!

Comment: Every curl request, get unix timestamp in seconds using `time();`, save into DB with that time and add +1 to a count field. You may have a bit of lag doing this though.

Comment: If you posted your code, I could make an answer more suited to you.

Comment: One way to go would be to use multi curl, send all 30 requests at once and then `sleep(1)`

Comment: This could also be done easier with apache or nginx or whatever you use :)

Comment: suppose that 1000 users make my curl  request script runs at one second! @Matt

Comment: Maybe PHP is not the best approach with that many requests, if you're using apache then there are plenty of modiles to limit the outgoing connections

Answer (score 1):

you can use `microtime` function in PHP to measure time accurately!
for example:

```
$uT = microtime(true);
$c = 0;
while($condition)
{
    # do curl, ... here
    if(++$c>29)
    {
        if( microtime(true) - $uT < 1)
            usleep(1E6*(1-microtime(true)+$uT));
        $uT = microtime(true);
        $c = 0;
    }
}
```